# HRM module stop working on the same project on which it is working earlier

Tags: vue.js, vue-cli-3

Hot reload module stop working on my project because of which i have to run this command each time i make any changes.

> npm run serve

Comment: Try to remove `node_modules` directory then reinstall them again `npm i`

Comment: Your welcome. I'll put this as answer, it may also be useful to others.

Answer (score 0):

This usually is `npm` packages problem and is often remedied by reinstallation

- first remove the `node_modules` directory in project root
- also you can clear the npm cache `npm cache clean --force`(this is optional)
- then reinstall packages `npm i`